# Can I calculate the size of my transformed element?

Tags: html, css, transform

For example, I apply to my element `perspective(200px)`, `transform: scale(1.5);` and `translateZ(100px)` properties. So, how can I calculate what size will have my transformed element? Is there any formula?

I think this question is more relevant when we use `perspective` together with `translateZ`, because mainly in these situations I don't know for sure how my element will look like.

```css
.green {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin: 50px;
  transform-origin: 400px 0px;
  transform: perspective(200px) scale(1.5) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="green"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't `300 * 1.5` cover it? Are you hoping to include the translation space resulting from the origin rule?

Comment: You can use `getComputedStyle` method in JavaScript, then get the new width and height in px.

Comment: @Ameer, answers go down there.

Comment: Computed style returns the width and height defined in the css sadly.

Comment: is it related to this particular case or you are looking for a generic solution?

Comment: @Temani Afif I'm looking for a generic solution. Does it exist?

Comment: for a generic formula good luck following the Spec and all the Matrix Calculation: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#accumulated-3d-transformation-matrix-computation .. you need to have a strong Math background and a lot of time

Comment: @Temani Afif Thanks. But unfortunately, I don't have a lot of time:) Is there an easier solution? Maybe you know... How do you usually do transformation when you need to get certain sizes of transformed element? Do you use this matrix calculation? I need something what I can use in the real situations. If you know something like that, I'll be very grateful:)

Comment: the easier solution is to consider each case alone. For a particular transform and a particular case I can reduce the formula to have something easy to deal with. I can give you the solution for this particular case, maybe it can help you?

Comment: @Temani Afif No. I'll try to allow my time and figure out how this formula works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear whether this fulfills your requirements, but it appears that [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) will return the transformed dimensions of the element:

```js
const elWithTransforms = document.querySelector('#elementWithTransforms');
const elWithoutTransforms = document.querySelector('#elementWithoutTransforms');

const transDimensions = elWithTransforms.getBoundingClientRect();
const noTransDimensions = elWithoutTransforms.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log(`Green element dimensions:\n    width: ${transDimensions.width}\n    height: ${transDimensions.height}`);
console.log(`Purple element dimensions:\n    width: ${noTransDimensions.width}\n    height: ${noTransDimensions.height}`);
```

```css
.green {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin: 50px;
  transform-origin: 400px 0px;
  transform: perspective(200px) scale(1.5) translateZ(100px);
}

.purple {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: purple;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green" id="elementWithTransforms" ></div>
<div class="purple" id="elementWithoutTransforms" ></div>
```

I wasn't certain if this was something you needed to do ahead of time on paper, or something you could do with JS in the browser.  If the latter, this should fulfill your needs.

If it is important that this happen before the element is visible, you have some options.  `getBoundingClientRect()` will return all zeroes if called before the element is attached to the DOM, but you can attach the element to the DOM offscreen/invisible and get the dimensions from `getBoundingClientRect()`, and then remove the element, do any additional work you need to do, and reattach it after unhiding it.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('green');
div.classList.add('hideOffScreen');
body.appendChild(div);

console.log(div.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
.green {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin: 50px;
  transform-origin: 400px 0px;
  transform: perspective(200px) scale(1.5) translateZ(100px);
}

.hideOffScreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```